# Firebase Analytics manual screen tracking not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Since the latest versions, it's possible to turn off the automatic screen tracking in Firebase Analytics and do it on your own calling the `logEvent` method by providing the screen class and screen name in a `Bundle`:

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, activity.localClassName)
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName)
}
```

However, I realized that the tracking isn't visible in the firebase console, even if I try to test it with the DebugView. I made the `logEvent` call in my Activity in the `onCreate` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ...
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, this.localClassName)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, "My Screen")
    }
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying different stuff and analyzing the code cautiously, realized that the problem is caused by making the call in the wrong lifecycle method. Instead of doing it in `onCreate` the `logEvent` call should be done after the activity`s state is resumed:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // ...
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, this.localClassName)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, "My Screen")
    }
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
}
```